# How to stop spring app from starting when redis connection can not be established

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

when I build and run my spring boot app, if the connection to postgres database can not be established, the app wont start too, but when this happen for redis connection, it only logs that redis couldn't be connected and the app starts anyway
But I want to happen same as postgres db connection
i have these on my .YML file :

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/sample
    username: postgres
    password: *********
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 300
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 5
      idle-timeout: 300000
  redis:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 6379
```

when postgres is not connected i get this :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException ...
.
.
.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63991', transport: 'socket'
```

but when redis can not be connected it logs this :

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
.
.
.
```